# Python starting a process in a particular time and ending it on a particular time

Tags: python, python-multithreading

This is a sample python code to run a process for every 5 seconds until 1 AM.

```
def run_check():
  mythrd =threading.Timer(5.0, run_check)
  mythrd.start()
  time = datetime.now()
  domystuff()

  if time.hour == 1:
    mythrd.cancel()

run_check()
```

I wanted to start the thread at a particular time. So I changed this code as below,

```
mythrd = None

def run_check():
  while (True):

    now = datetime.now
    if now().hour == 16 and now().minute == 30 and now().second == 30:
      mythrd.start()
      time.sleep(1)
    if mythrd.is_alive():
      domystuff()

    if datetime.now().hour == 16 and datetime.now().minute == 31:
        mythrd.cancel()

mythrd =threading.Timer(5.0, run_check)
run_check()
```

Earlier, I kept `mythrd` object inside the `run_check` function. If I initialize inside the `run_check` function, It will act that object as a new object. And It will trigger again. So I defined `mythrd` function as a global object. But It keeps running. I want to start the process at a particular time and ending it on a particular time. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized this solution for you:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading
import time

class test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.run_permission = False

        self.start_time = [16,30,30] # Hours, Minutes, Seconds
        self.end_time = [18,41,00] # Hours, Minutes, Seconds

        self.timer_sched_time = 5 # seconds

        threading.Thread(name="time_checker", target=self.check_time, args=(self.start_time, self.end_time,)).start()
        threading.Thread(name="scheduled_job", target=self.Timer, args=(self.timer_sched_time, )).start()

        while True:
            time.sleep(10)

    def timer_job(self, unix_time, human_time):
        print "Unix time: %s  Human time: %s \n" % (unix_time, human_time)

    def Timer(self, delay):
        while True:
            try:
                time_remaining = delay-time.time()%delay
                time.sleep(time_remaining)

                unix_time = str(int(round(time.time()*1000)))
                human_time = str(dt.now())

                if(self.run_permission):
                    self.timer_job(unix_time, human_time)

            except Exception, ex:
                raise ex

    def check_time(self, start_execution_time, end_execution_time):
        while True:
            now = dt.now()

            if(now.hour >= start_execution_time[0] and now.minute >= start_execution_time[1] and now.second >= start_execution_time[2]):
                self.run_permission = True

            if(now.hour >= end_execution_time[0] and now.minute >= end_execution_time[1] and now.second >= end_execution_time[2]):
                self.run_permission = False

test()
```

**As first thing import the library that you need:**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading
import time
```

**Create a class named test:**

```
class test(object):
```

**Definite the `__init__`, it will be execute at the creation of the class test when you call it using `test()`:**

```
def __init__(self):
        self.run_permission = False

        self.start_time = [16,30,30] # Hours, Minutes, Seconds
        self.end_time = [18,41,00] # Hours, Minutes, Seconds

        self.timer_sched_time = 5 # seconds

        threading.Thread(name="time_checker", target=self.check_time, args=(self.start_time, self.end_time,)).start()
        threading.Thread(name="scheduled_job", target=self.Timer, args=(self.timer_sched_time, )).start()

        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
```

The variable `run_permission` is a boolean that is used as flag to check if is possible to execute the job in the timer.

The `start_time` variable set the start time for the `check_time` routine that write the `run_permission` variable to `True` if the time is major or equal to the `start_time`

The `end_time` variable set the stop time for the `check_time` routine that write the `run_permission` variable to False if the time is major or equal to the `end_time`

The `timer_sched_time` variable set the delay for the timer, the delay is needed to calculate the sleep time, it grant the perfect time execution each 5 seconds: 17.00.00 - 17.00.05 - 17.00.10 - 17.00.15 etc etc

**This two lines starts the threads for the `check_time` job and the `Timer` job:**

```
threading.Thread(name="time_checker", target=self.check_time, args=(self.start_time, self.end_time,)).start()
threading.Thread(name="scheduled_job", target=self.Timer, args=(self.timer_sched_time, )).start()
```

**This two line keep the Main thread running, but sleep the main thread to reduce the resource consumption:**

```
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

The function `timer_job` just print the time in Unix format and Human readable format:

```
def timer_job(self, unix_time, human_time):
        print "Unix time: %s  Human time: %s \n" % (unix_time, human_time)
```

To translate the unix format you can use the [epoch converter website](https://www.epochconverter.com).

The `Timer` function calculate the time to sleep to grant the execution to the perfect time, take the timestamp in unix and human format and pass it to the `timer_job` if the `run_permission` variable is set to `True`:

```
def Timer(self, delay):
        while True:
            try:
                time_remaining = delay-time.time()%delay
                time.sleep(time_remaining)

                unix_time = str(int(round(time.time()*1000)))
                human_time = str(dt.now())

                if(self.run_permission):
                    self.timer_job(unix_time, human_time)

            except Exception, ex:
                raise ex
```

The check_time function use the arguments `start_execution` _time and `end_execution_time` to set the variable `run_permission` to `True` or `False` if the time execution condition are respected ( so if the hours/minutes/seconds range is respected ):

```
def check_time(self, start_execution_time, end_execution_time):
        while True:
            now = dt.now()

            if(now.hour >= start_execution_time[0] and now.minute >= start_execution_time[1] and now.second >= start_execution_time[2]):
                self.run_permission = True

            if(now.hour >= end_execution_time[0] and now.minute >= end_execution_time[1] and now.second >= end_execution_time[2]):
                self.run_permission = False
```

As said previously the `test()` at the end of the file call the test class and initialize the program using the `__init__` function.

Comment: It Just works fine. Thank you for the detailed explanation. It will really helpful for the beginner like me. I have a question. Should I increase the sleep time in the constructor function, If I run the job for every 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You just have to edit this value:  `self.timer_sched_time = 5 # seconds`. This variable is the schedulation time expressed in second. So if you multiply 60 seconds in a minute and 30 minute that is the schedulation time, you obtain 1800. Write in the code: `self.timer_sched_time = 1800 # seconds` and the job will be executed every perfect 30 minute

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with this code.
First, when looping inside a thread and no condition is hit, add a sleep to save CPU use.
Second, since threads are non deterministic, you cannot trigger conditions on exact timestamps. For instance the thread might skip its execution during the "hot" time interval and the condition will never trigger.

Therefore you can instead check if the current timestamp has passed a certain timestamp (and by how much) and/or otherwise compare timestamps.

But regardless, in your code mythrd starts a thread function that will call itself recursively.... this is the problem.

```
mythrd =threading.Timer(5.0, run_check)
```

and then

```
mythrd.start()  # will start threading.Timer(5.0, run_check)
```

So when the condition `now().hour == 16 and now().minute == 30 and now().second == 30` triggers, the thread will run another instance of itself. This instance might run another instance and so on...

Did you mean to implement a trigger thread, performing `run_check` duties but then start another thread performing the actual work?

Here is a solution:

```
from threading import Thread, Timer
import time
import datetime

keep_checking = True
keep_working = True

def worker_thread():
    while keep_working:
        pass #do my stuff here and remember to use an eventual sleep

def time_checker():
    while keep_checking:
        now = datetime.now()
        if now.hour == 16 and now.minute == 30 and (
           now.second >= 30 and now.second < 31) and (
           not mythrd.isAlive()):
            mythrd.start()
        elif now.minute >= 31 and mythrd.isAlive():
            keep_working = False # and let it die instead to kill it
        else:
            time.sleep(1) # no operation

mythrd = threading.Thread(target=worker_thread)
time_checker() # might turn this into a thread as well
```

Remember that you need to define the exact time intervals in which the thread is on and those in which it is off. Cover all those cases with conditions and act accordingly. A mutex might become necessary later as your project becomes more complex.

Comment: I want to create a new thread for every particular time, do the task and close the thread. If the process ends before that particular time, the It should go to sleep until the next thread triggered.

Comment: Is this new thread that you wish to run for every particular time, always the same function? And in this case, what if the thread function is still running but another particular time condition kicks in? Do you wish to enqueue and wait for the running instance to finish, skip it, or run another instance?

Comment: I am new to python. 1) Running the same thread to run the same process and sleep until the next process time. 2) Create a new thread for every particular time. I think this is the two methods may probably applicable to my task. I don't know what is efficient?

Comment: Gotcha. This doesn't handle the case where the thread is still running and a new time condition kicks-in but ok I will update my answer

Comment: Ok. If the process starts at <16:30>, when will it end? Will it run for every <5 seconds> until the time is <17:15>. 
<>, are arguments.

Comment: Ah. So this is your necessity. In my example it ends at 16:31. If you need to run it every 5 seconds, why not putting a sleep of 5 seconds inside the thread loop? And when the checker thread meets the stop condition, it will set the flag to false. (no abrupt interruptions in this case)

Comment: My thought is to run this process at 18:00 everyday and to stop and 23:00. When I started to work on this the time is 16:00. So for example, i used that time labs. Second thing, If i started the thread on particular time, next instruction also will run on the same time. And since every instructions getting finish in nano seconds, thread start process also could be run again on the same time. So I put sleep for one second so that starting the thread will trigger only one time in a day. Thats what I used sleep(1)

Comment: Then use a mutex or even a simple boolean, to prevent double instantiations. Is my answer satisfactory or do you need more help?

Comment: Carlo Zanocco gives me the exact answer I want. Thank you for your detailed explanation and time. I learned a lot from your help. It will be really helpful for a beginner like me.